# Spring Webflux Netty - HttpProxyConnectException 503 Service Unavailable, but for who?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Currently using the latest Spring Boot 2.5.1 with Webflux, I have to make an HTTP outbound call to a third party app, via a proxy.

The call is like: my app -> proxy -> third party rest API

Upon the call, I am observing in my logs:

> io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpProxyConnectException:
> http, none, myproxy.com/someIP:443 => third-party.com:443, status: 503
> Service Unavailable

The complete stack trace below.

May I ask, who, which one of the two is unavailable please? The 503 comes from the proxy, or coming from the third party please?

```
r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id:85c9790c, L:/ip:54246 ! R:proxy.com/proxyIP:443] The connection observed an error
io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpProxyConnectException: http, none, proxy.com.com/proxyIP:443 => third-party.com:443, status: 503 Service Unavailable
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler.handleResponse(HttpProxyHandler.java:200) ~[netty-handler-proxy-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelRead(ProxyHandler.java:258) ~[netty-handler-proxy-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:271) ~[netty-handler-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelRead(HttpProxyHandler.java:272) ~[netty-handler-proxy-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollRdHupReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:480) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:487) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.65.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar!/:4.1.65.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Given the name of the exception is `HttpProxyConnectException`, I'm guessing it happens when connecting to the proxy, so the problem would be the proxy, but I don't actually know the internals.

Comment: This is the whole point of a reverse proxy. To hide the internals, so you not knowing is exactly what its purpose is. You check the logs from the proxy or the service. Thats how you find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking logs from 1, local app, 2, proxy appliance, 3 destination app, this error means it is the destination app who is 503 service unavailable. The logs indicates the third party app is having issue, not the proxy